# Flexslider - advance to next slide via on click

Tags: jquery, flexslider

hoping someone can help me with a Flexslider question.

Here's a link to the slider:

http://www.findspace.co.uk/FINDSPACE2014/pages/3bed_biddrdb.html

I would really like to add an onlick function so that users can click on the current main large image and advance to the next slide. I don't mind if the directional arrows need to come off to achieve this. I guess it would need to also go back to the initial slide at the end of the sequence.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Antony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
directionNav : false,
slideshow: false,
animation: "slide",
controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
start: function(slider) {
$('.slides li img').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
});
}
});
```

:)

Comment: Hi Bojan - sorry for the delayed reply. Thank you for responding though I can't seem to get this to work - probably my error somewhere. This is the code I currently have:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 124,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });
   
  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
});

Comment: I wasn't sure how to integrate the code you supplied into mine - Antony

Comment: Okay - managed to get it to work - my mistake, I was missing some brackets. Is there any way the pointer could show a hand for the hover?

Comment: You can add it with css on the image, .slides li img{ cursor: pointer; } And if the code worked you should accept the answer :)