# Flexslider - click image to advance to next slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using the current (mid-2017) version of Flexslider and am trying to alter the code so that a click on an image advances the slider to the next slide. 
I am aware that this question has been answered for previous versions but do not know how to alter/insert the code for the jquery.flexslider-min.js of the new Flexslider plugin.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
directionNav : false,
slideshow: false,
animation: "slide",
controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
start: function(slider) {
$('.slides li img').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
});
}
});
```

Comment: To avoid confusion: The code above stems from Bojan Petkovski's answer from 2014: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104112/flexslider-advance-to-next-slide-via-on-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're loading things onto your page, but if you put the following on the page(in script tags), the slider should go to the next slide on img click.

```
<script>
$('.slides li img').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#slider').flexslider("next") //Go to next slide
});
</script>
```

If you are loading this jQuery in an external file, exclude the script tags. Make sure it comes after the flexslider code. Also, you may have to replace `$` with `jQuery`. And, you need to have the class `slides` on the slide container.

That's right from the [repo docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider).

Comment: @ icicleking Thank you. Could you further specify where in the  jquery.flexslider-min.js I have to integrate the given code? The file is extensive and my insertions where unsuccesful. Here is the original script: http://textuploader.com/d4obd

Comment: @DarioLanfranconi You don't add the code to the flexslider code, you add it to your own code. I'll update my answer in a way that I hope helps.

Comment: The problem is that I installed flexslider as a wordpress plugin and its not clear where the code is printed and referenced. I wrote a support ticket now for woocommerce, thank you for the detailled information and explanations though.

Comment: @DarioLanfranconi Some themes and a number of plugins give you the ability to add scripts to the footer of the page. A quick search should give you some decent ones. You can either learn to use the inspector to see where on the page ` jquery.flexslider-min.js` is loaded, or a pretty safe assumption is that the custom snippet will be inserted below most other scripts. I will also guess that if you go this route you'll need to use `jQuery` to replace the `$` in the snippet I supplied above.

Comment: @ icicleking The Chrome inspector reveals that `jquery.flexslider-min.js' is visible (but greyed out) at the bottom of the script structure like you said. This is my page: https://web80.sr45.firestorm.ch/architekturdarstellung/ The footer.php is called for in the page.php file, but adding the code snippet to the footer.php in all variations (jQuery, $, w/o script tags) did not bring any change yet.

Comment: Only load it once, `preventDefault` may cause issues. The script is loading above flexslider, I wouldn't expect it to work. I'm not intimately familiar with WordPress, but I seem to recall there's a `wp` function that adds the page footer (ie. the flexslider code and others). Adding the script directly to the footer template is obviously not going to get it low enough. I'd suggest looking for a plugin to help or using wordpress's tools: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/